# Sitting with the sun on my face

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does it mean: **"Sitting with the sun on my face..."**? I don't entirely understand that expression exactly.

*This phrase is from my American grammar book.*

Comment: Sitting with the sun shining on your face. Shining is the main thing the sun is known for.

Comment: Or sun meaning sunlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main action is **sitting**. The rest of the phrase modifies the main action: How are you sitting? You are sitting *such that the sun is [shining] on your face*.